# Calculating the variance of the sum of $X_n$'s

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, variance, covariance

You have $n$ random variables $X_n$ which each have $\mathbb{E}(X) = 0$ and $\text{Var}(X) =1$. The pairwise correlation between any distinct of these is $\rho$.

So the variance is

$$\text{Var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n \text{Var}(X_i) + \sum_{i \neq j}\text{Cov}(X_i,X_j)$$

Now $\text{Cov}(X_i,X_j)= \rho \times \sigma_X \times \sigma_Y = \rho$. So,

$$\text{Var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i\right) = n-1+ \sum_{i=1,i \neq j}(n-1)\rho = n-1 + (n-1)^2\rho$$

Is this correct? The double sum is throwing me a bit.

Comment: Small error: $\sum_{k = 1}^{n} 1 = n \ne n - 1$.

Comment: but surely there needs to be a $-2$ for $X_i,X_j$ and $X_j, X_i$

Comment: Shouldn't there be a 2 in front of the double sum?

Comment: In the first sum $\sum\operatorname{Var}(X_i)$ you are summing $n$ lots of $\operatorname{Var}(X_i)=1$. In the second double sum, you are summing over all *ordered* pairs $(i,j)$ with $i\neq j$, as $i,j$ vary between $1$ and $n$. How many such pairs are there?

Comment: @jlammy $n^2 -2$?

Comment: @Trajan there are $n$ choices for $i$ (namely $1,2,\dots,n$). Given an $i$, how many choices are there for $j$ s.t. $i\neq j$?

Comment: @jlammy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bienaym%C3%A9%27s_identity these are not ordered?

Comment: Yes they are e.g. we have both terms $\operatorname{Cov}(X_1,X_2)$ and $\operatorname{Cov}(X_2,X_1)$ included in the sum. So $(i,j)=(1,2)$ is different from $(i,j)=(2,1)$.

Comment: @jlammy sorry my misunderstanding

Comment: So the answer is $n +n(n-1)\rho$ ???

Comment: @Trajan Correct!

Comment: @jlammy add an answer and collect some credit for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{Cov}{\operatorname{Cov}}$
$\newcommand{Var}{\operatorname{Var}}$
The formula states $$\Var\left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n\Var(X_i)+\sum_{i\neq j}\Cov(X_i,X_j).$$
If the double sum is confusing you, it might be worth writing it out in full for small values of $n$, e.g.
\begin{align*}
\Var(X_1+X_2)=\Var(X_1)&+\Var(X_2)+\Cov(X_1,X_2)+\Cov(X_2,X_1) \\
\Var(X_1+X_2+X_3)= \Var(X_1)&+\Var(X_2)+\Var(X_3)\\
&+\Cov(X_1,X_2)+\Cov(X_2,X_1) \\
&+\Cov(X_2,X_3)+\Cov(X_3,X_2) \\
&+\Cov(X_3,X_1)+\Cov(X_1,X_3).
\end{align*}
You'll note that the double sum is over all ordered pairs $(i,j)$ with $i\neq j$ as $i,j$ each vary between $1$ and $n$. So we want to know the number of such pairs (which is the number of lots of $\rho$ that we are summing).

There are $n$ choices for $i$ (namely $1,2,\dots,n$). Given an $i$, there are then a further $n-1$ choices for $j$ s.t. $i\neq j$. So we have $n(n-1)$ terms in the double sum.

Putting everything together, you get a final answer of $\boxed{n+n(n-1)\rho}$.